# How do I install drivers for an HD6950?

Tags: 10.04, drivers, ati

I have a HD6950 graphics card and a fresh install of ubuntu 10.04. 
I have a SyncMaster 2032BW monitor that can handle resolutions upto 1680x1050.

Ubuntu will only let me put my resolution upto 1280x1024, calls my monitor 'Unknown' and won't let me enable any visual effects.

There are no entries in System>Administration>Hardware Drivers.

I've been looking at the guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI).

and there is an AMD driver [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English).

I was wondering if I should try and install the proprietary driver manually or the opensource driver.

I would appreciate some advice as I can't get a decent resolution or visual effects that I could on my old 8800GT!

Answer (score 1):

You are already running the open source driver probably. If you want to test the proprietary driver use [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates).

Add it to your system with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-installer
```

This will install the proprietary drivers in your system. Hope it works, any faults or doubts drop a comment.